# ios14.5: An app runs away on start gobbling up memory

Tags: ios, infinite-loop

this
Thread 9 Queue : fmdb.<YMMFMDatabaseQueue: 0x600002bd0690> (serial)

is responsible for a lot of mallocs invoked.
What does this thread do and who made it?

UPD: my guess was 100% off. And the issue had nothing to do with rx either. I'm embarassed to the point of editing rx out of the title.

Comment: Well, I made an off the wall guess and failed. Found the root cause by accident.

Answer (score -1):

in my particular case that was an endless loop
with constant relayout in viewWillLayoutSubviews()
I had to check if frames have changed before touching them.
Apparently ios15,16 does this by itself.

```
if let bounds = view.superview?.bounds {
            if backgroundImageView.frame != bounds {
                backgroundImageView.frame = bounds
                allowResize = true
            }
            if collectionView.frame != bounds {
                collectionView.frame = bounds
                allowResize = true
            }
        }
        if allowResize {
            locationButton.sizeToFit()
        }
```

I don't understand why the developer that wrote the code
I had to fix did not just use strings and struts and had
this abomination with the manual frame setup. Shrug.